# Google Guava Cache - cleanUp and invalidateAll

Tags: java, caching, guava

The documentation is not really that clear for those two methods.
I will go with a straight question: which one should I use to free the heap from the cached objects?
Looking at the source code of `LocalManualCache` and `LocalCache` it seems `invalidateAll()` is the way to go, as the `Segment`'s table's entries are setted to null.
So what is the meaning of `cleanUp()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `CacheBuilder` Javadoc:

> If expireAfterWrite or expireAfterAccess is requested entries may be evicted on each cache modification, on occasional cache accesses, or on calls to Cache.cleanUp().

`cleanUp` goes through and makes sure elements that have expired are actually evicted, because the design of Cache doesn't necessarily evict entries instantly when they expire.  It doesn't eliminate *all* entries, just those that have expired.  `invalidateAll` removes every entry in the cache.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks for the clarification Louis.